# wrong Initial state in zustand in nextjs server side

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, zustand

I use zustand as a global state manager and I want use of the persisted states in server side of nextjs pages. but when I log the currently state values it will print default values (which the default values are null) and it does not log the updated states values.

The codes are here:

store.ts

```js
/**
 *? For more information about config zustand store in nextjs visit here:
 *? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-zustand/lib/store.js
 */

import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

import create, { StoreApi } from 'zustand';
import createContext from 'zustand/context';
import { devtools, persist, PersistOptions } from 'zustand/middleware';

import { createClinicSlice } from './slices/clinic';
import { createUserSlice } from './slices/user';

import type { IClinicSlice, IResetState, IUserSlice } from '$types';

const persistProperties: PersistOptions<any> = {
  name: 'globalStorage',
  getStorage: () => localStorage,
  // ? should update version when app version updated
  version: 0,
};

let store: any;

interface IInitialState {
  clinics: null;
  activeClinic: null;
  user: null;
}

const getDefaultInitialState = (): IInitialState => ({
  clinics: null,
  activeClinic: null,
  user: null,
});

const zustandContext = createContext<StoreApi<IClinicSlice & IUserSlice & IResetState>>();

export const Provider = zustandContext.Provider;
export const useStore = zustandContext.useStore;

export const initializeStore = (preloadedState: Record<string, any> = {}) => {
  return create<IClinicSlice & IUserSlice & IResetState>()(
    devtools(
      persist(
        (set) => ({
          ...getDefaultInitialState(),
          ...preloadedState,
          // @ts-ignore
          ...createClinicSlice(set),
          // @ts-ignore
          ...createUserSlice(set),
          resetStore: () => set(getDefaultInitialState()),
        }),
        persistProperties
      )
    )
  );
};

export function useCreateStore(
  serverInitialState: Record<string, any>
): typeof initializeStore {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return () => initializeStore(serverInitialState);
  }

  const isReusingStore = Boolean(store);
  store = store ?? initializeStore(serverInitialState);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // serverInitialState is undefined for CSR pages. It is up to you if you want to reset
    // states on CSR page navigation or not. I have chosen not to, but if you choose to,
    // then add `serverInitialState = getDefaultInitialState()` here.
    if (serverInitialState && isReusingStore) {
      store.setState(
        {
          // re-use functions from existing store
          ...store.getState(),
          // but reset all other properties.
          ...(serverInitialState || getDefaultInitialState()),
        },
        true // replace states, rather than shallow merging
      );
    }
  });

  return () => store;
}
```

_app.tsx

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { ThemeProvider, jssPreset, StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { create } from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { ThemeProvider as SCThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

import muiTheme from '$/assets/style/theme';
import { AuthProvider } from '$/components/contexts/auth';
import { ReactToastify } from '$/components/ReactToastify/ReactToastify';

import { Provider, useCreateStore } from '$store';

import '../../public/assets/style/index.css';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-geosearch/assets/css/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-geosearch/dist/geosearch.css';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import '$/utils/i18n.config';

const jss = create({
  plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()],
});

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement!.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  const createStore = useCreateStore(pageProps.initialZustandState);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, user-scalable=no"
        />
      </Head>
      <Provider createStore={createStore}>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
          <ReactToastify />
        </I18nextProvider>

        <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
            <SCThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
              <CssBaseline />
              <AuthProvider>
                <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
                </I18nextProvider>
              </AuthProvider>
            </SCThemeProvider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </StylesProvider>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

dashboard/index.tsx

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { PageScrollableArea } from '$/components/index';
import ClinicDashboardLayout from '$/components/layout/clinicDashboardLayout/ClinicDashboardLayout';
import { isNil } from '$/utils/stringUtils';
import ClinicDashboard from '$/view/clinic/Dashboard';
import withPrivateRoute from '$/view/hocs/withPrivateRoute';

import { CLINICS_PAGE_URL } from '$constant';
import { initializeStore, useStore } from '$store';

const Dashboard: NextPage = (props) => {
  return (
    <ClinicDashboardLayout>
      <PageScrollableArea>
        <ClinicDashboard />
      </PageScrollableArea>
    </ClinicDashboardLayout>
  );
};

export default withPrivateRoute(Dashboard);

export function getServerSideProps() {
  const zustandStore = initializeStore();
  console.log(`===> zustandStore.getState() ===>`, zustandStore.getState());
  // if (isNil(zustandStore.getState().activeClinic)) {
  //   return {
  //     redirect: {
  //       destination: CLINICS_PAGE_URL,
  //       permanent: true,
  //     },
  //   };
  // }
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

I find out the store variable in `store.ts` file always is undefined and its value will not update as values are located in local storage

Does anybody have a similar experience with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Since NextJS performs a static optimization serverside, if you persist the modified Zustand store and try to load it before render, NextJS will detect that the result obtained serverside is different from the actual result.
The solution in this case is not to use the zustand store directly to affect UI elements, but use a React **useState** and set the persisted state in a **useEffect** in this way this will happen after render and NextJS won't complain about it.

In code terms, I use this custom hook to wrap the Zustand store:

```js
export const useSSRStore = (store) => {
    const [_store, setStore] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        setStore(store);
    }, [store]);
    return _store;
};
```

And use it like this:

```js
const {
        isDarkMode,
        isRightSectionVisible,
    } = useSSRStore(useUIStore());
```

Where `useUIStore()` returns the original Zustand store.